# Match string to regepx using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I have a string with some path. It looks like `.../my/test/....`, I want to mutch all string where exists `/my/test/`. But I am newbie in RegEpx and dont know how I can do this? I need to escape `/`? I try something like this:

```
\"[^/"]+/my/test/+[/$]
```

but wont work (and I think cant work). Can somebody help me please?

Comment: `str.indexOf("/my/test/")` comes to mind ?

Comment: @adeneo, yes, but for my special purposes I want to use regexp.

Comment: `str.match(/\/my\/test\//)`

Comment: You can check your tries here: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want get full string [try this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/aY0lF1/1)

```
^.*\/my\/test\/.*$
```

Answer (score 1):

you can escape  '/' by using '/' 
your expression can be something like /my/test//g

explanation of the expression + reference of regex is here:
https://regex101.com/r/cG5aA3/1

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?\/my\/test\/.*$
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/26

```
var re = /^.*?\/my\/test\/.*$/gm;
var str = 'asdd/as/d/as/dasdas/my/test/asdasd/s/a/dsa/\nasdd/as/d/as/dasdas/my/notest/asdasd/s/a/dsa/';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```